# Frobenius methon for ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, frobenius-method

I was reading about Frobenius method for solving 2nd order ODE and I found two examples which I couldn´t solve. I would appreciate any kind of help:

1. ${u}''-2u'+(1+\frac{1}{4z^2})u=0$
2. ${u}''+\frac{1-z}{z(1+z)}u'-\frac{1-z}{z(1+z)^2}=0$

Comment: What have you tried?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: Is there supposed to be a $u$ in the third terms of those equations?

Comment: I apologize, it was my mistake. I have just started reading about it, we still haven´t discussed it at the lecture, and I am not sure how to approach the problem at all.